# Data between view controllers not passing

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, swift2

I am creating an application in which there are 6 view controller in storyboard. The thing is that data is shared between the default view controller and the first one ( say A and B) which i added. i am using the prepareforseque method for passing data. the problem started when i added two more view controller. lets say C and D i created two new swift files and changed the two view controller class name. i created a textbox and button in C and label in D. when i pressed the button, the value of the text field is not passing into the D view controller although i used the same methods and code which i used for A and B. do i have to do anything else when i want to pass data between two newly added view controller.

first viewcontroller in which when a button is pressed value 1 needed to be passed:

```
class PlaySelectMenu: UIViewController {

var value = Int()

@IBAction func twotofive(sender: AnyObject) {

    value = 1
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let nextView : PlayGameView = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayGameView
      nextView.x = value
}
}
```

the second view controller which receive the value and print it

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PlayGameView: UIViewController{

var x = Int()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(x)
}
}
```

here i have added both the view controller from the object library and not working with the default one which is present in storyboard by default. i dont know why these two viewcontroller are not working. please help.
Regards Dev

Comment: Can you post the code inside your different viewController please ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write the data out to NSUserDefaults and then read it back from NSUserDefaults in the other view controller. Probably not the proper or correct way to share data between two view controllers, but it's been a reliable work around for me.

Other than that, you'd need to share your code so that we can see what's occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post also the code in your controllers C & D. And also if you have copy/paste the code inside your first two controllers into the two others, are you sure that in your `prepareForSegue` method you have changed the name of the destination segue ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created the segue in Storyboard:

All you need is to do is put all of needed updates in `prepareForSegue` because `twotofive` is called after `prepareForSegue`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    value = 1
    let nextView : PlayGameView = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayGameView
    nextView.x = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have connected your segue from button click to view controller, when you press button segue is automatically called. Instead of connecting segue from button to VC, connect VC to VC. Then in button click method at the last add below line:

```
@IBAction func twotofive(sender: AnyObject) {

    value = 1
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("<Name of the segue identifier>", sender: self)
}
```

This will call your prepareForSegue. If you are calling more then one VC using segue from a VC then you can use segue.identifier to check which VC was called as below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "CVC" {

}
```